# how to get data into an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I saved the result of a CURL expression into variable $data. When I print this value using print_r($data), It gives me like that

```
stdClass Object
(
    [zip_codes] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [zip_code] => 10015
                    [distance] => 0.521
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [zip_code] => 10079
                    [distance] => 0.521
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [zip_code] => 10094
                    [distance] => 0.521
                )
```

I want only zip_code into an array, Please help me how do I get only zip_code into an array.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map):

```
$result = array_map(function($x)
{
   return $x->zip_code
}, $obj->zip_codes);
```

Comment: Great solution! Didn't know it :D

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
foreach($data->zip_codes as $zipObj)
{
  echo $zipObj->zip_code;
}
```

This will loop over the zip codes array and output the relevant value.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
First iterate trought the collection of objects an get the zip code property and add it to an array

```
<?php
    $result = array();
    $zipCodes = $data->zip_codes;
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($zipCodes); $i++){
      $result[] = $zipCodes->zip_code;
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_map](http://www.php.net/array_map), this function allows you to apply a callback to the array.

```
$zip_codes = array_map(function($i) { return $i->zip_code; }, $data->zip_codes);
```

Comment: This is the same as [Alma Do's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22251031/1438393) except that you've made some minor cosmetic updates.

Comment: I'm sorry but when I was answering the question there was no other comment only when I gave out the other 4 answers.